Display Vendor, Product and Serialnumber unknown
I installed my new TETRA split keyboard.
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/747287659/tetra-keyboard-split-touch-type
Keyboard and display works fine.
But I cannot map the touch event to the display because it is not recogniced.
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>3099</x>
      <y>2160</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-9</connector>
          <vendor>unknown</vendor>
          <product>unknown</product>
          <serial>unknown</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1280</width>
          <height>800</height>
          <rate>60.004</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>

I'm running Fedora 40 / Gnome 46 / wayland.
The display is connected via displaylink on usb-c.

EDID seems correct
